# openai gym, env.spaces, observation_space representing an incremental value

Tags: openai-gym

Lets say I have a snake game I want to train using custom env, I have an array 'snake_body' which is the position of the body (each block of the snake), as it eats the apple, the body increases. Now I want that to be an observation space so it learns not to eat itself. So what gym.space to use to represent this value (because the array keeps increases as the game prceeds). Need to change the self.observation_space.

```
self.snake_body = [[100, 50],
                  [90, 50],
                  [80, 50],
                  [70, 50]
                  ]

self.observation_space = Box(low=0, high=400, shape=(5,),dtype=np.int32)
```